# How to vary height of div based on browser window width

Tags: jquery, gallery, fullscreen

I am looking to achieve the effect of a 'fullscreen' photo gallery which fills the screen but ALSO allows fixed-height content above, and content that you can scroll to below.

I know this is a little abstract, so here's an example: http://pixelthemes.net/immersion/

- Notice how you can resize the browser window, but the almost-fullscreen gallery 'sticks' to the bottom of the browser window, whilst still allowing you to use the scroll bar to see what's below it
- Notice how the above behaviour is consistent even as you resize the browser window

The above example uses the jquery gallery "Supersized" but I will be using Galleria (latest version has a 'responsive' option allowing dynamic resizing of gallery stage).

Of course, with a fullscreen gallery, there will always be crop - however this is not an issue for me.

I presume this isn't possible with pure CSS, so how do I achieve this using existing jquery plugins?

Better still, I've a feeling this can be done using Galleria API (http://galleria.io/docs/api/methods/#display) but I'm not experienced enough to know exactly how.

Comment: Have look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455353/align-element-to-bottom-of-window-but-allow-scrolling-to-content-underneath/11456665#11456665). This is a very basic way to achive your target with JavaScript.

Comment: That's basic CSS with a little JS sprinkled on top. Look at the site you are linking to, find it's [stylesheet](http://pixelthemes.net/immersion/wp-content/plugins/bwp-minify/min/?f=immersion/wp-content/themes/immersion/css/base.css,immersion/wp-content/themes/immersion/css/skeleton.css,immersion/wp-content/themes/immersion/css/layout.css,immersion/wp-content/themes/immersion/css/colorbox.css), and notice the [media queries](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/).

Comment: I don't have an answer but just want to say that's an awesome site - nice font, colours, slideshow etc.

Comment: Thanks Torsten, and adeneo for the useful links. I'm testing this out, and it's looking good so far: http://www.matsmithphotography.com/assets/scripts/g127/galleria/themes/classic/classic-demo.html